# Trouble making text disappear in code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, visibility, p5.js, visible, invisible

I'm simply trying to get the text to disappear when the mouse hovers over a sprite, and it won't do that. I've tried many things - putting text(A/B).visible = true; in an else statement. I've moved my text code just about everywhere in my program. It just won't disappear.

````
var alien = createSprite(100, 200);
alien.setAnimation("alienYellow_jump_1");
var bubble = createSprite(225, 250);
bubble.setAnimation("comictextbubble.png_1");
var button = createSprite(105, 275);
button.setAnimation("play_1");
function draw() {
  background("lightblue");
  if (mouseIsOver(alien)){
    alien.rotation = randomNumber(10, -10);
  }
  button.visible = false;
  if (mouseIsOver(button)){
    button.visible = true;
  }
  if (mousePressedOver(button)){
    bubble.visible = false;
  }
  drawSprites();
  stroke("black");
  textSize(20);
  var textA = text("Find the secret button to reveal your card!", 10, 207);
  var textB = text("It's your birthday!", 115, 150);
  if (mouseIsOver(button)){
    textB.visible = false;
    textA.visible = false;
  }
  console.log(textA.visible);
  console.log(textB.visible);
}```
````

Comment: I have also added a console log to check whether the program is actually recognizing what the if statement wants to do, and lo and behold, it does recognize that whenever hovered over the button, the visibility is supposed to be "false." But it still does not change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: If this s P5. please tag it so. The page to read is https://studio.code.org/docs/gamelab/visible/

Comment: @mplungjan What are the visible and invisible tags usually for?

Comment: @jperl If we mouse over them, they are very generic and not part of a specific framework or browser methods

Answer (score 0):

Did you try if you move your mouse over the sprite, the fill color for the text becomes transparent, if you set the 4th parameter of the fill function to 255, then it's transparent.

```
    function draw(){

     var Red = 255;
    var Blue = 255;
    var Green = 255;
    var Alpha = 0;
    fill(Red,Green,Blue,Alpha);
    text("Move mouse over me to disappear",200,200);
    if(mouseX>175&&mouseX<225&&mouseY>175&&mouseY<225)
        {
    Alpha=255;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that's because the top statement is setting the visibility to true when the mouse is over the sprite, preventing the bottom statement from working properly. Try adding an `else` statement, like this:

```
      if (mouseIsOver(button)){
    button.visible = true;
  } else if (mousePressedOver(button)){
    bubble.visible = false;
  }
```

If that doesn't work, make sure that the visibility function is actually making the sprite invisible.